# In VueJS how to determine the element width of an element within the template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a VueJS app which creates two divs in a container div which are layed out with `display:flex` like so:

```
 +-------------------------------------------+
 | div#app                                   |
 | +---------------------+ +---------------+ |
 | |                     | |               | |
 | |       div.a         | |     div.b     | |
 | |                     | |               | |
 | +---------------------+ +---------------+ |
 |                                           |
 +-------------------------------------------+
```

Inside `div.a` is an svg element which is generated by Vue too.

I need to know the width dimension of `div.a` in order to generate suitable SVG. Any ideas how to go about finding this out?

Comment: Have you tried exploiting `this.$el.clientWidth` ?

Comment: it's the width of the `div.a` I need, not `div#app`

Comment: Ah sorry. Then instead of `this.$el`, you can use the `ref` tag on your div (for example `<div ref="myDiv">...</div>`), and access it using `this.$refs.myDiv`, and get the `clientWidth` propery from there.

Comment: @Seblor that worked! thanks - do you want to put that as an answer and I'll accept?

Comment: There already is a valid answer, you can accept it, I don't mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to wait until after the component is rendered and then grab a reference to the elements using `$refs`. Here's an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  mounted () {
    const divA = this.$refs.divA
    
    console.log('inner width is: ' + divA.clientWidth)
  }
})
```

```css
.ct {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.a {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;
}

.b {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="ct">
    <div class="a" ref="divA"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that this won't track resizing, you'd need to measure it again when size changes occur.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I've added an event listener on window.resize to cause a recalculation of the sizes. Note also, we need to set 'overflow:hidden' on the divs because otherwise you can't ever shrink the window (because flex allows for the content, so if content is large..)